# ¿Como hacer que un programa en WPF baje actualizaciones?

Tags: wpf, update

Tengo un programa en WPF con metodología MVVM y lo tengo en gitHub, asi que cada que le hago cambios subo esos cambios al git desde el Visual Studio 2019.

Pero quiero que el programa baje esos cambios (a modo de actualizaciones) en el pc donde este instalado.

Algo asi como un botón para que el usuario que tenga el pc desde su maquina actualice el programa.

Comment: De donde descargara el programa las actualizaciones? De github o de un servidor dedicado especificamente para eso?

Comment: En Github tienes los códigos fuente supongo, pero no el compilado, no puedes integrar código en un compilado. Lo que tienes que hacer es entrar a PUBLICAR en el menú de PROYECTO -> Propiedades de.. y configurar un host de carga y descarga además del número de la versión.

Comment: @Einer Pues es lo que no se... supongo que localmente en el pc donde se esta ejecutando el programa.

Comment: @Leodev Gracias ¿Donde puedo hallar documentación del tema?